# Need some help to write json for multilevel listview. ^^

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am trying to implement a multilevel listview in my application (android based). I am using **php** and **mysql** together with eclipse.

For the first level listview, this is the json (**filename:test1.php**):

```
[
    {"id":1,
     "name":"Agensi Anti Dadah Kebangsaan",
     "code":"AADK"},

    {"id":2,
     "name":"Agensi Kelayakan Malaysia",
     "code":"MQA"},

    {"id":3,
    "name":"Agensi Penguatkuassan Maritim Malaysia",
    "code":"MARITIM"},

    {"id":4,
     "name":"Akademi Seni Kebudayaan & Warisan Kebangsaan",
     "code":"ASWARA"},

    {"id":5,
     "name":"Arkib Negara Malaysia",
     "code":"ARKIB"}
]
```

Now, for the second level listview, where the referring url would be `test2.php?id=1` (or any other id number) - How do I write the json in `test2.php`?

Do I have to write all the listview data for each item in the previous listview? Or do I have to make several `test2.php` files corresponding to each item in the previous listview?

Suggestions, advice and tutorial links are much welcomed and appreciated.

Comment: Do you write application on Java? Is it native android application or you use some custom framework for android based on php?

Comment: Oh yes, I am using JAVA. I pretty much referred to http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-multilevel-listview-tutorial/ .

Answer (score 0):

Your titorial use simple ListView wich is a part of ListActivity. To fill this list with data they use SimpleAdapter with fill with JSON responce from server.

```
 ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
       AlbumsActivity.this, albumsList,
        R.layout.list_item_albums, new String[] { TAG_ID,
        TAG_NAME, TAG_SONGS_COUNT }, new int[] {
        R.id.album_id, R.id.album_name, R.id.songs_count });
```

All data in adapter taked from

```
albumsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

This ArrayList filled by the code in AsyckTask:
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List params = new ArrayList();

```
        // getting JSON string from URL
        String json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_ALBUMS, "GET",
                params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("Albums JSON: ", "> " + json);

        try {               
            albums = new JSONArray(json);

            if (albums != null) {
                // looping through All albums
                for (int i = 0; i < albums.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = albums.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item values in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String songs_count = c.getString(TAG_SONGS_COUNT);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_SONGS_COUNT, songs_count);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    albumsList.add(map);
                }
            }else{
                Log.d("Albums: ", "null");
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

You can add your JSON object directly in code and don't use Prelode from Server. And simple pare like in example:
albums = new JSONArray(json); // Here is your JSON ARRAY object. Could be constructed from String

```
            if (albums != null) {
                // looping through All albums
                for (int i = 0; i < albums.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = albums.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item values in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String songs_count = c.getString(TAG_SONGS_COUNT);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_SONGS_COUNT, songs_count);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    albumsList.add(map);
                }
            }else{
                Log.d("Albums: ", "null");
            }
```

**UPDATE:** If you click on items in first list (album) you call new activity and pass there album ID

```
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TrackListActivity.class);
        // send album id to tracklist activity to get list of songs under that album
        String album_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.album_id)).getText().toString();
        i.putExtra("album_id", album_id);               
        startActivity(i);
```

I think inside this Activity they do AsyncTask query againe from server and get another JSON wich is parsed in the same way as in first activity.

If you click on SONG in TrackerActivity you launch new activity with Ditails of this song.

**UPDATE 2:**

On server side you need to organaize JSON Oblect generator for:

1. Albums list ([example](http://api.androidhive.info/songs/albums.php))
2. Albums songs ([example](http://api.androidhive.info/songs/album_tracks.php?id=1))
3. Song ditail ([example](http://api.androidhive.info/songs/track.php?album=3&song=1))

Comment: Actually, I have already completed the tutorial successfully before. Then I wanted to output my own data in the listview. The test.php file mentioned worked well with the first level listview. Now I need help to make test2.php for the second level listview. I don't know should I write the json objects.

Comment: Yes, you need to write almost the same JSON object as for first level. But this JSON will contain only list of songs, not albums. And you should generate different objects according to album id. (I missunderstand your question, I think you asked about client side, not about server side)

Comment: Sorry to bother you any further, but could you please give me some advice? Do you have to put codes like this into album_tracks.php (file from the tutorial)?

{"id":1,"album":"127 Hours","songs":[{"id":1,"name":"Never Hear Surf Music Again","duration":"5:52"},{"id":2,"name":"The Canyon","duration":"3:01"}]}

{"id":2,"album":"Adele 21","songs":[{"id":1,"name":"Rolling In The Deep","duration":"03:48"},{"id":2,"name":"Rumour Has It","duration":"03:43"}]}

Comment: No, this code should be for URI like this: album_tracks.php?id=1 where you pass ID of album. and return this JSON Object: http://api.androidhive.info/songs/album_tracks.php?id=1

Comment: If my answers help you solved your problem you can UP vote my answer and marked it as Accepted Answer. It will show you thanks.